# Python Scrapy - parse URL content for most recent updated date

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a webcrawler/scraper that's written in Python using the scrapy framework. I've been trying to use the "last-modified" date to identify the most recent update for each page - but I also collect each HTML file for the pages that are scraped. Is there a more accurate method for collecting the date each page was most recently updated?

Answer (score 0):

There’s [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) if you just need to know *if* the data changed rather than *when*.

Otherwise, as far as information from the server goes, `Last-Modified` is usually it, unless the specific target server provides the same information in some other way (alternative custom header or response content).

If that’s not good enough, the next best things would be to monitor from the client side for changes. Which is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you! I think the last-modified will be fine if it's available. I know a lot of documents won't have a last-modified date. I'm just having trouble parsing that date. It'll have to be an if/then type of response - if available, return last-mod, else null. I'm just struggling to get the html parsing to work.